# I don't have access to Lombok features of my entity class from test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, lombok

I have an entity class in my src/main/java directory like this:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email_address",
    nullable = false
    )
    private String emailId;
    private String gaurdianName;
    private String gaurdianEmail;
    private String gaurdianMobile;

}
```

In my test class in src/test/java directory I don't have access to Lombok features in my above class like setters and getters, builder methods and other features of Lombok.

Where is the problem?

In my test class I want to make an object of student class with builder method or use getter and setter methods like this:

```java
Student student = new Student();

student.setFirstName("John"); // it doesn't work
student.getFirstName(); // it doesn't work
Student student = Student.builder().firstName("JOHN").build(); // it doesn't work
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```xml
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add provided to the Lombok dependency in your maven file. this will enable this dependency for test classpath as well. as like this doc

https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven

Comment: how can I add provided? is this a tag in lombok dependency?

Comment: how about lombok in exclude tag ? should I remove it or not?

Comment: look about this 
https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven

Comment: I found the solution I have not added the lombok plugin to my IDE. that was the case.